# How i use value in function to other function

Tags: php, arrays, function

Now i have function and value `$data` Query in other file

```
function template_head($data){
      $data[0]["name"];
      $data[0]["last-name"];
}
```

But i have problem when i want to use `$data["name"]` for other function

> this problem

```
 template_meta($data["name"]);
```

use

```
function template_meta($name){
    foreach ($name as $var) {
              .
              .
              .
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: than pass same as in other function.

Comment: include that file and use that variable. pass that variable in your all funvctions

Comment: your description is little bit unclear. Could you please describe more or add some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy example for you:-

abc.php:-

```
<?php

$data = array(0=>array("name"=>'A',"last-name"=>'B'));
?>
```

def.php:-

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL); //check all type of errors
  ini_set('display_errors',1); // display those if any happen
  include('abc.php'); // include file


function template_M42_head($data){
      echo $data[0]["name"].'<br/>';
      echo $data[0]["last-name"].'<br/>';
}


function template_M43_head($data){
      echo $data[0]["last-name"].'<br/>';
      echo $data[0]["name"].'<br/>';

}

template_M42_head($data);
template_M43_head($data);
```

Output:-

```
A
B
B
A
```

What you shown now,do like below:-

```
$name_data = template_meta($data["name"]);
```

And either:-

```
foreach ($name_data as $name_dat){

}
```

Or

```
function new_template_meta($name_data){
    foreach ($name_data as $var) {
              .
              .
              .
}

new_template_meta($name_data);//call the function
```

Comment: u can make it very simple `$functionA = template_head($data);
$functionB = template_meta($functionA);`

Comment: @AlohajungVipatchavatee  glad to help you. :):)